# When were GADTs introduced in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt

When were GADTs introduced in GHC? (version + date)

Also, are they still considered a language extension or are they now part of the Haskell standard proper?

Comment: If you're interested in the history of GADTs you might want to look at this paper, [Silly Type Families](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/papers/silly.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GADTs were first supported in [ghc-6.4](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.4/html/users_guide/release-6-4.html), which was released in March 2005.

They are still a language extension, the latest standard, Haskell2010, has not adopted them (since it was a GHC-only extension, afaik).